# Converting a context free grammar to a PDA -- is my solution correct?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, context-free, pushdown-automata

I'm reviewing for my midterm and wanted to post this to see if anyone can spot any errors. Im supposed to make a PDA that recognizes this CFG:

$\qquad\begin{align}
  S &\to R1R1R1 \\
  R &\to 0R \mid 1R \mid \varepsilon
\end{align}$

Here is my solution; I'm aware that I forgot to draw the second circle around my accepting state.

[image]

Comment: Your course probably mentions the (simple) standard translation algorithm. Have you tried to apply it? (Also, that image is hard to decipher.) Which one *is* supposed to be the final state? Finally, not that "check my answer" questions tend to work not so well on SE (in the case that the answer is a boring "yes, no mistakes".

Comment: Checking out [this question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3205/when-generating-a-pda-from-a-cfg-do-i-have-a-receiving-state/3206#3206) might help.

Answer (score 8):

Doesn't that language simply recognize any string in $\{0,1\}^*$ that has at least three $1$s in it?

If so, you just need a regular finite deterministic automaton with that can count up to three in order to recognize it.

[image: finite automaton that counts to three]

---

This is because I'm not on the mood to do a direct translation of that grammar, if that is what you really wanted to check :P