# CFG and PDA for the grammar that has perfectly nested parentheses and brackets

Tags: formal-languages, automata, formal-grammars, context-free, pushdown-automata

I gotta make a CFG and PDA for the grammar that has perfectly nested parentheses and brackets.

$\qquad\begin{align}
 S &\to [S] \\
 S &\to (S) \\
 S &\to SS \\
 S &\to \varepsilon
\end{align}$

Not sure if this is correct, or how to make the PDA from it?

Comment: Try using the standard construction from the proof that CFG and NPDA are equally powerful! Does "perfectly nested" exclude $([)]$ here?

Answer (score 3):

The language you study is a classic, the one-sided Dyck language (on two pairs of brackets). You can directly make a PDA by considering the following property of nested strings: every symbol closing bracket you read should match the last unmatched opening bracket. Keep the unmatched $[$ and $($ on the stack and you are ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

A: your CFG looks good.

B: There is a very well-known method of converting CFGs to PDAs.

Check https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MJ9xNavURY8

Or the [Wikipedia article on Pushdown automata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton)

also [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/3205/157) has some interesting details.

But mainly -  google "Converting CFG ro PDA".