# Need to give a CFG for this language?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

I have the language:

$$ L = \{0^m1^n \mid 0 ≤ m ≤ n\text{ or }0 ≤ n ≤ 2m\}. $$

My goal is to give an equivalent context-free grammar for this language, but I am unsure if I am going about it the right way. So far this is what I've come up with:

$$
\begin{align*}
    &S \to A \mid X \\
    &A \to 0A1 \mid A1 \mid \varepsilon \\
    &X \to 00A1 \mid 00A \mid \varepsilon
\end{align*}
$$
Is this anywhere close?

Comment: Is this supposed to be the same language as [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/54217/converting-a-language-to-a-pda)?

Comment: See http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/18524/755

Comment: @bobafro Are you sure it is OR in the language and not AND?

Comment: It is supposed to be or, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is pretty close but a little far, correct solution will be (if you go about writing grammar methodically)

$S \rightarrow A \ | \ B$
$A \rightarrow 0A1\  |\  A1 \  |\  \epsilon$
$B \rightarrow 0B11\  |\  0B \  |\  \epsilon$

Otherwise, if you go by logic,  condition $0 \leq m \leq n$ OR $0 \leq n \leq 2m$ is true for every non-negative integer pair $m$ and $n$ (because $m \leq n$ OR $n \leq m$ translates to $m \leq n$ OR $n \leq m \leq 2m$, which is always true). Hence your language is really $\{0^m1^n\ |\ m\geq 0, n\geq 0\}$ and the grammar is:

$S \rightarrow 0S \ | \ S1 \ | \ \epsilon$

Comment: Your grammar generates $\{0^m 1^n \mid m \leq n \leq 2m\}$. This is not quite what the OP is after (you have AND whereas OP has OR).

Comment: Sorry, for the silly mistake, I did not correctly see the problem.

Comment: I am surprised, who gave this answer -1, without asking for an explanation, or without telling what is wrong in this answer.

Comment: @Shreesh. You'll just make your self crazy worrying about such things. Accept the fact that you'll occasionally get random unexplained downvotes. I'll counter the downvote as a favor.

Comment: @RickDecker, Thank you, I was just surprised who thought that such an obvious answer is wrong.