# What is the pushdown automata for the language {0, 1}* Where |0| = 2 * |1| or |1| = 2 * |0|?

Tags: pushdown-automata

Having a lot of trouble figuring this out.

It seems to me to be impossible. I could do one side of the OR - but the fact that the string can begin with 100 1's and then have 200 b's seems like it can't be accounted for. Am I supposed to just stack every single a and b it traverses, and then somehow find a way to compare the numbers of each? Seems impossible.

Comment: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/18524/755, http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/11182/755, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language#Closure_properties

Comment: [Also posted on Math.SE]()http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1835257/14578.
Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.